# Mostrar datos de la consulta en un toast

Tags: java, android

Quiero mostrar los datos de la consulta en un `Toast` y no lo realiza, este es mi código:

```
    conn3 = DBConnection3.getInstance().getConnection();
    try {
        String stsql="Select a.idOperario,b.IdLlamada,b.Fecha,b.Mensaje,b.De,b. IdUsuarioDestino,b.Estado,b.IdUsuarioCrea from xTRAINING.dbo.tbUsuarioOperario a INNER JOIN WorkFlow.dbo.Llamadas b ON a.idOperario=b.IdUsuarioCrea where Estado=0 and CUsuario='"+t1+"'ORDER BY IdLlamada asc";
        Statement st = conn3.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(stsql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            IdLlamada = rs.getInt(1);
            Fecha = rs.getDate(2);
            Mensaje = rs.getString(3);
            De = rs.getString(4);
            IdUsuarioDestino = rs.getString(5);
            Estado =rs.getBoolean(6);
            IdUsuarioCrea=rs.getString(7);
            IdOperario=rs.getString(8);
            Cusuario=rs.getString(9);

            consulta5 = "IdLlamada" + rs.getInt(1) + " Fecha " + rs.getDate(2) + " Mensaje " + rs.getString(3) + " De " + rs.getString(4) + " IdUsuarioDestino " + rs.getString(5) + "Estado" + rs.getBoolean(6)+" IdUsuarioCrea " + rs.getString(7)+" IdOperario " + rs.getString(8)+ " CUsuario " + rs.getString(9);
            System.out.println("IdLlamadas.getInt(1) + " Fecha " + rs.getDate(2) + " Mensaje " + rs.getString(3) + " De " + rs.getString(4) + " IdUsuarioDestino " + rs.getString(5) + "Estado" + rs.getBoolean(6)+" IdUsuarioCrea " + rs.getString(7)+" IdOperario " + rs.getString(8)+ " CUsuario " + rs.getString(9));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "registro de llamadas perdidas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,consulta5,Toast. LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

El error lo tengo en el `getText()` de la consulta:

```
 String stsql="Select a.idOperario,b.IdLlamada,b.Fecha,b.Mensaje,b.De,b.IdUsuarioD‌​estino,b.Estado,b.Id‌​UsuarioCrea from xTRAINING.dbo.tbUsuarioOperario a INNER JOIN WorkFlow.dbo.Llamadas b ON a.idOperario=b.IdUsuarioCrea where Estado=0 and CUsuario='"+t1.getText()+"'ORDER BY IdLlamada asc";
```

¿Cómo lo arreglo? ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Te recomiendo que, si quieres que alguien te eche una mano y no huya nada más abrir tu pregunta con el mazacote de código en línea que has puesto, hagas tu pregunta en un formato más amigable. Puedes apoyarte en la [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: lo tendre presente para la proxima puedes  darme alguna solucion?

Comment: el error le tengo en el getText de la consulta como lo arreglo?                                String stsql="Select a.idOperario,b.IdLlamada,b.Fecha,b.Mensaje,b.De,b.IdUsuarioDestino,b.Estado,b.IdUsuarioCrea from xTRAINING.dbo.tbUsuarioOperario a INNER JOIN WorkFlow.dbo.Llamadas b ON a.idOperario=b.IdUsuarioCrea where Estado=0 and CUsuario='"+t1.getText()+"'ORDER BY IdLlamada asc";

Comment: Pon el StackTrace completo para ver el error

Comment: @TAMARUSS agregué una respuesta, debes usar el método toSting() de lo contrario estas obteniendo la representación del Widget.

Comment: @Tamarus recuerda agregar el espacio que indico en mi respuesta

Comment: @Tamarus que error obtienes?

Answer (score 1):

**Debes usar el método `toString()` para obtener correctamente el valor introducido dentro del `EditText`.**

```
t1.getText().toString();
```

de lo contrario no estas obteniendo el valor dentro del EditText, probablemente obtienes algo similar a:

```
android.widget.EditText@12345ff0
```

**Suponiendo que dentro de tu EditText t1 estas escribiendo correctamente el nombre del usuario**, usa el método `.toString()` y  de esta forma tu query se construiría correctamente (agrega también un espacio en `' ORDER`) ya que obtendrás el valor  que se contiene dentro del `EditText` :

```
String stsql="Select a.idOperario,b.IdLlamada,b.Fecha,b.Mensaje,b.De,b.IdUsuarioD‌​estino,b.Estado,b.Id‌​UsuarioCrea from xTRAINING.dbo.tbUsuarioOperario a INNER JOIN WorkFlow.dbo.Llamadas b ON a.idOperario=b.IdUsuarioCrea where Estado=0 and CUsuario='"+t1.getText().toString()+"' ORDER BY IdLlamada asc";
```