# Abrir URL desde EditText

Tags: android, edittext, botón

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación parecida a un *browser* pero sin `WebView`, simplemente un `EditText` en el que pones una *URL* y al presionar cierto botón abre dicha *URL* en el navegador predeterminado. Por si no se entendió, dejo más o menos lo que tengo hasta ahora, no es mucho por el momento:

***XML***

```
<Button
    android:text="IR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp" />
```

Código:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;

public class actividad extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText et1;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);

  }

 public void ejecutar(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Actividad.class);
    i.putExtra("direccion", et1.getText().toString());
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Cual es tu problema, no se entiende bien tu consulta?

Comment: Simplemente quiero abrir una URL desde un edittext con un boton, para resumir

Comment: aca hay un ejemplo http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Implicit_Intents_%E2%80%93_An_Android_Studio_Example

Comment: Vi muchos ejemplos parecidos mi problema esta en llamar la URL desde el EditText

Comment: Los ejemplos no estás hechos de forma estricta para lo que buscas, en este caso solo es cambiar la URL por el texto obtenido del edittext algo como edittext.getText()

Comment: @FrancoGaluzzi es importante usar el método toString() para que obtengas correctamente el valor dentro del EditText, de lo contrario no funcionará. edittext.getText().toString(), agregué una respuesta.

Comment: @Elenasys agregue esa recomendacion a mi respuesta, gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Para Abrir URL a partir del contenido de un `EditText`.

Necesitas obtener el valor del contenido dentro del `EditText`, en este caso una url que hayas escrito, realizas un [Intent definiendo un action como ACTION_VIEW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW).

```
  //Obtienes la referencia del EditText.
  myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
  //Obtienes el text (url) dentro del EditText y defines ACTION_VIEW .
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myEditText.getText().toString()));
  //abre el Intent.
   startActivity(intent);
```

**Es importante usar [.toString()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33937/95)** para obtener correctamente el valor dentro del EditText.

de acuerdo a tu código , con esto puedes abrir el url que especifiques dentro de tu EditText:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(et1.getText().toString()));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, es posible que el intent tenga una URL y el EditText la complete? Por ejemplo que el intent contenga http://Google y en el EditText completar con el dominio de tu país (.com .es) es un ejemplo nada más y solamente como prueba

Comment: En el caso de un intent con ACTION_VIEW se podría realizar de esta forma "http://www.mydominio"+ Uri.parse(et1.getText().toString() puedes definir un dominio y completarla con el contenido del EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear un `Intent`

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(et1.getText().toString()));
startActivity(intent);
```

Tambien deberias validar que lo que se ingreso en el `EditText` es una URL valida

```
if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(et1.getText().toString()){
    Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(et1.getText().toString()));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Para hacerlo desde el boton

```
Button buttonUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
buttonUrl.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(et1.getText()){
           Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(et1.getText().toString()));
           startActivity(intent);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias pude resolverlo

Comment: Agregue tambien para hacerlo desde el boton, saludos!